# To convert a group of meaningful words in short form

Tags: java

Like for example: united states of america it should print USA and not USOA it should excludes words like of,and,with:

```
import java.io.*;

class m dabest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        InputStreamReader cr = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(cr);
        int i, oy, l;
        String st,er;
        char r,n;

        st = in.readLine();
        er = " " + st + " ";
        l = e.length();
        for (i=0; i < l-1; i++) {
            r = er.charAt(i);
            if (r == ' ') {
                for (oy=i; oy < i+1; oy++) {
                    n = er.charAt(oy);
                    System.out.println(n + " ");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Split the string on whitespace, remove token words like `"of"` and `"the"`, and extract the first letters of the remaining words.  Actually, there is probably a library somewhere to do a better job at this.

Comment: where is your code? explain your problem statement in more detail!

Comment: Also, you should include the code you have tried already.  SO is not a pump and dump free code writing service.

Comment: Hi user4989960, welcome to Stackoverflow! Questions need to have a [clear problem statement](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If you provide a code sample, someone may be able to help you with this. The [Asking a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) is worth a read too.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen  I added the code

Comment: I formatted your code, but it is not clear what you are trying to do.  Have a look at my first comment to get you started thinking about this problem.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen how did u formatted my code and did u ran my code and checked the output

Comment: I didn't run your code because it won't solve your problem.  Please read the Stack Overflow user guidelines.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen i got the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import java.io.*;

class mdae
{
    public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException
    {
        InputStreamReader cr = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(cr);
        int i, oy,l;
        String s,q,ioo=" ";
        char c,v;
        s=in.readLine();
        s=s.replaceAll("of","");
        q=" "+s+" ";
        l=q.length();
        for(i=0;i<l-1;i++)
        {
            c=q.charAt(i);
            if(c==' ')
            {
                for(oy=i;oy<=i+1;oy++)
                {
                    v=q.charAt(oy);
                    if(v!=' ')
                    {
                        ioo=ioo+v;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.print(ioo);
    }
}
```